# Дано комп и Debian, как сделать переустановку ОСИ по SSH

Tags: linux, debian, hosting, xen, виртуальная-машина

Именно комп, а не сервак с iDRAC ))
Думаю сделать минимальные разделы для основной оси и оставить место для виртуальной.
На основную накатить xen например... и пошло поехало.
Есть ли готовые пакеты для этого?

Comment: Я на libvirt сижу, а так есть готовая ось - proxmox. Оч популярна

Comment: Мы proxmox в проде юзаем. Пока что очень довольны. Пара лет - полёт нормальный.

Answer (score 0):

готовое решение не встречал, а пошаговая инструкция есть: https://habr.com/ru/post/321696/

кратко - создаётся окружение в памяти c ssh, подключаемся к нему по ssh, и производим переустановку системы ОС, будто это виртуалка